# React Native build warning issue?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native

After running `react-native init reactApp` I get a warning `npm WARN react-native@0.39.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed`. The build is successful though and here is my package.json after the build.

```js
{
  "name": "reactApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "15.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.39.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "18.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.1",
    "jest": "18.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Is this an issue? Should I change the react version and then run `npm install` ? I'm completely new to react/react-native so any advice would be appreciated as to best practices to prevent errors in the future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been working with React Native for like 3 weeks. While running `react-native init Proj` I had similar warning:

> npm WARN react-native@0.39.2 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed.

and also

> npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
>
> npm WARN prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

However, it did not affect my work. I haven't faced any problems while writing the code and running it.

You can always run:

`npm install --save react@15.4` and it should fix it  but your version is currently the newest one so I would not do it.

Answer (score 0):

React Native will work with earlier versions of React, but it's not guaranteed. If you want to, you can update your React version to fix the peer dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this issue. Updating react/react-native versions to the latest fixed my problem.

## package.json

```
"react": "^16.0.0-beta.5",
"react-native": "0.47.0",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.0.0-beta.5"
```